# How to decide which whitespace to split by in regex?

Tags: python, regex

I need to process some text with many whitespace as follow,

string_many_whitespace = "k1@v1 k2@[v1 v2 v3] k3@v1"

```
import re

string_many_whitespace = "k1@v1 k2@[v1 v2 v3] k3@v1"
print(re.findall('(.+?@.+?)', string_many_whitespace))
```

output:

```
['k1@v', '1 k2@[', 'v1 v2 v3] k3@v']
```

As you see, they were split by wrong whitespace.

What I really want is:

```
['k1@v1', 'k2@[v1 v2 v3]', 'k3@v1']
```

Edit:
Sometimes the item is kUPPER@value, not always lowercase or digit, such as

"k1@v1  k2@[v1 v2 v3]  kUPPER@value"

Comment: What is your desired output? FYI, you're not even splitting on anything, you're just getting matches and it is working as expected based on the regex you've shown.

Comment: Adding to @MonkeyZeus: You need to be clear on the data format rules to have a chance of doing this correctly. There is no reason to prefer your intended result to the observed behavior unless you've defined clear rules for your e-mail address-like format. It's not a matter of single examples; you need real rules (e.g. can there be spaces in the segment preceding the `@`?).

Comment: @MonkeyZeus  Sorry, I have update the desired output.

Comment: Yes, I see that. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @ShadowRanger You're right, we should define better format. But this text data is from my client, it got me into trouble.

Comment: @KenNieh: The problem is your question is literally unanswerable for the general case unless there are rules. Solving it for this specific scenario is trivial (of course, you could just manually slice it when you only need to solve one case). Solving it for the *next* thing your client sends you is where you need rules.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, I think I need to talk about it with my client next week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
re.compile("(?= [a-zA-Z]+\d*@) ").split(string_many_whitespace)
```

You can see here that it targets the correct spaces: https://regex101.com/r/EPG1CI/1

Comment: @KenNieh You're welcome, is the `k1@`, `k2@`, etc... always a single lowercase letter, followed by a single digit, followed by an `@` symbol? Would there ever be multiple letters, digit, or uppercase letters?

Comment: Sometimes it's kaU@value, maybe not followed by a digit.

Comment: @KenNieh so the letter is guaranteed but not the digit? Always a lowercase letter?

Comment: Not always a lowercase letter or the digit. Sorry for my Imperfect question

Comment: @KenNieh It's respectful to allow a person to try and fix up their answer before unaccepting it especially since you keep adding new information. Please update your question with a proper sample string that has the variants you expect.

Comment: You're good at guiding me to better question, and your answer is concise and correct. Sorry for my rudeness.

Comment: @KenNieh Yes, always be responsive to the comments requesting clarification and add them to your question so that everyone can see. As of now I refer to your question as a game of whack-a-mole; and people don't like whack-a-mole when it comes to programming. There is no good reason for me (nor others) to have to read comments on other people's answers to figure out your newfound rules.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern that you tried `(.+?@.+?)` will match as least as possible chars until it can match a single char after encounting an @ because it is non greedy giving you the wrong output.

---

You could be more specific in what you would allow to match and use an alternation `|` to match either the square brackets version or the version without an @ after the initial @.

It matches at least a single non whitespace char after the `@` to not match only `k3@`

```
[^\s@]+@(?:[^][\s@]+|\[[^][]*])
```

**Explanation**

- `[^\s@]+` Match 1+ times any char other than @ or a whitespace char
- `@` Match the @
- `(?:` Non capture group to match either

  - `[^][\s@]+` Match any char except @ [ ] or a whitespace char
  - `|` Or
- `\[[^][]*]` Match from `[` till `]`
- `)`  Close the group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JGbw99/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/cHCdHX)

```
import re

regex = r"[^\s@]+@(?:[^][\s@]+|\[[^][]*])"
s = "k1@v1 k2@[v1 v2 v3] k3@v1"

matches = re.findall(regex, s)
print(matches)
```

Output

```
['k1@v1', 'k2@[v1 v2 v3]', 'k3@v1']
```

Answer (score -2):

use split, regex will simply destroy performance for such simple problems.

```
txt = "welcome to the jungle"

x = txt.split(" ") #returns list without white spaces aka [welcome, to, the, jungle]
```

Comment: This reads like you saw "regex" and "split" and read absolutely nothing else in the OP's question. It doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @CoffeDev Sorry for my Imperfect question